# Trouble installing Elementary desktop environment on Ubuntu 15

Tags: apt, desktop-environments, 15.04, elementary

I am trying to install `elementary-desktop` on Ubuntu 15.04 but when running `sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop` I get a slew of recommends/errors with this at the top:

```
elementary-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-extras-keyring but it is not    installable
... long list of Recommends
```

and this at the bottom:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, yes this post is about Ubuntu. I am trying to install a desktop environment *on* Ubuntu 15.04 and the `ubuntu-extras-keyring` package is missing.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am afraid Elementary is off-topic here. Please try https://elementary.io/en/support or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Comment: `elementary-desktop` is not a Ubuntu supported package. If this question is about the derivative of Ubuntu "Elementary OS", then it's off-topic here.

Comment: Ok thank you. The problem is more related to the fact that I can't install ubuntu-extras-keyring, but I'll make a new post for that

Comment: @Zach [We do support installing third party software on Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) Please clarify your situation--are you running Elementary OS or Ubuntu? This also is fundamentally important to understanding this question from a technical perspective; I don't think this can really be answered without that information. If you are running Ubuntu and trying to install a desktop environment (like Elementary's) on your Ubuntu system, we should reopen this (but the solution will be about getting the software sources working and wouldn't likely apply to an Elementary OS system).

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, to clarify I am trying to install the desktop environment on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run

```
mkdir somedir
cd somedir
sudo apt-get install -y debhelper
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-extras-keyring/ubuntu-extras-keyring_2010.09.27.{tar.gz,dsc}
tar -xf *.tar.gz
cd ubuntu-extras-keyring-2010.09.17
debuild -i -us -uc -b
sudo dpkg -i ../ubuntu-extras-keyring_2010.09.27_all.deb
```

After that, elementary-desktop will install, but will error out at the end because it depends on systemd-shim which is no longer needed nor wanted with 15.04 having a full SystemD implementation.

When it errors out, run

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -r indicator-datetime
sudo apt-get purge unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon
```

and it should complete the installation.

Comment: debuild: command not found

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install devscripts' fixed it

Comment: now I have: dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -i -b failed

Comment: turns out I was missing build-essential: 'sudo apt-get install build-essential'